# Karate - how to check if array contains values?

Tags: arrays, cucumber, karate

#### Given

I have defined array

```json
 * def array = [ 
     {"code": "codeA", "boolValue": false, "a": 5, "c": false}, 
     {"code": "codeA", "boolValue": true, "a": 7, "c": true},
     {"code": "codeB", "boolValue": true, "a": 1, "c": false}
   ]
```

And variable

```json
 * def expected = { "code": "codeB", "boolValue": true }
```

#### Issues

In the last element of `array` there is `expected` value.
But it contains some additional values and that's why it failed all the time I try to check that.

How to check if array contains expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in 0.9.6.RC4:

```
* match array contains deep expected
```

In prior versions:

```
* match array contains '#(^expected)'
```

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#schema-validation