# How can we assert against nested objects within JSON arrays for **match contains**?

Tags: karate

How can we assert against nested objects within JSON arrays for  **match contains**

```
 Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
    Then match cat.kittens contains [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
```

As seen in the example, I am not worried about 'age'. I understand that I can use '#ignore'. Is there any other way, If I have lot of such nodes that I have to ignore.

I am just thinking, can it work with JSON arrays as it does with JSON Objects. asserting only specified nodes.

error:

```
assert.feature:24 - path: $.kittens[*], actual: [{"id":23,"name":"Bob","age":35},{"id":42,"name":"Wild","age":25}], expected: {id=42, name=Wild}, reason: actual value does not contain expected
```

**EDIT:**

I tried something suggested in [Karate - how to check if array contains values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395373/karate-how-to-check-if-array-contains-values)
but that did not help me. I am not looking for schema-validation instead I am looking for functional validation where every object may have different values for keys.

Below one fails

```
  Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
      * def expected = [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
    Then match cat.kittens contains '#(^expected)'
```

This one works fine but this is not helping me.

```
  Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
      * def expected = { id: 42, name: 'Wild' }
    Then match cat.kittens contains '#(^expected)'
```

Currently, I am reading a arrays separately and asserting them with loop.

Comment: I believe you can achieve it with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/great-json-validator