# Deep assertion on JSON array with contains in Karate

Tags: karate

```
 Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
    Then match cat.kittens contains [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
```

As seen in the example, I am not worried about 'age'. I understand that I can use '#ignore'. Is there any other way, if I have lot of such nodes that I have to ignore.

I am just thinking, can it work with JSON arrays as it does with JSON Objects. asserting only specified nodes.

error:

```
assert.feature:24 - path: $.kittens[*], actual: [{"id":23,"name":"Bob","age":35},{"id":42,"name":"Wild","age":25}], expected: {id=42, name=Wild}, reason: actual value does not contain expected
```

**EDIT:**

I tried something suggested in [Karate - how to check if array contains values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395373/karate-how-to-check-if-array-contains-values)
but that did not help me. I am not looking for schema-validation instead I am looking for functional validation where every object may have different values for keys.

Below one fails

```
  Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
      * def expected = [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
    Then match cat.kittens contains '#(^expected)'
```

This one works fine but this is not helping me.

```
  Scenario: 
    Given def cat =
      """
      {
        name: 'Billie',
        kittens: [
          { id: 23, name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
          { id: 42, name: 'Wild', age: 25 }
        ]
      }
      """
      * def expected = { id: 42, name: 'Wild' }
    Then match cat.kittens contains '#(^expected)'
```

Currently, I am reading arrays separately and asserting them with loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the word `deep` works in 0.9.6.RC4

```
Then match cat.kittens contains deep [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
```

I don't understand why the linked answer when I closed your first question did not help you. Maybe I don't understand, and someone else can provide a better answer.

Comment: Its works like a champ with 0.9.6 RC4. But I am not sure how  `Then match cat.kittens contains '#(^expected)'`  works for this case in 0.9.5

Comment: @kishorereddy I don't understand your question. read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation - I leave it to others here to provide a better answer if possible